# How to get the Output of a component that has been dynamically injected twice (nephew)?

Tags: angular, angular-components

In Angular2 I have this:

```
<parent>
    <child> // is injected from <parent>
        <nephew> // is injected from <child>
        <nephew> // is injected from <child>
        <nephew> // is injected from <child>
        <nephew> // is injected from <child>
```

`<nephew>` has an @Output, but its dynamically injected from `<child>`, which is dynamically injected from `<parent>`

I did the injections inside `<parent>` with the `createComponent` from [`ViewContainerRef` class](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef)

```
@ViewChild('editfield', {read: ViewContainerRef}) editfield: ViewContainerRef;

this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicFormComponent);
const ref = this.editfield.createComponent(factory, this.editfield.length, this.editfield.parentInjector, []);
```

While the `<nephew>`s are a list of components from the [DynamicFormComponent](https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da) of which some are custom

I don't how to access to the Output of `<nephew>` since the `ref.instance` that I have on `<parent>` talks about `<child>`, not `<nephew>`

Comment: what do you mean with dynamically injected?

Comment: edited, sorry :)